# How to drop multiple columns in spark with scala with some regex?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Say I have some column names which ends with '_undo', Now I need to remove this columns. Now instead of dropping one by one or storing them in a list before dropping, can i drop at one go?

```
df.drop(//drop at one go for those columns ending with _undo)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val customDF = df.select(df.columns.filter(colName => checkname(colName)) .map(colName => new Column(colName)): _*)
```

where checkname is simple user function which returns colname if matches and null if not. Use your pattern to check inside that function.

```
def checkname () : [return type] = {
   return [expr]
}
```

Comment: @Thankyou @Gokul , I would like to know is there some performance overhead with `df.drop` and `df.select`

Comment: I'm not sure but in-place operations would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
df.drop(df.columns.filter(c => "regexp".r.pattern.matcher(c).matches): _*)
```

or

```
df.drop(df.columns.filter(_.endsWith("_undo")): _*)
```